# Como usar un string en findIndex Javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objeto

tengo una duda y es que quiero usar keys como el parametro a buscar por el findIndex, pero como me lo toma en string, no lo usa como parametro.

```
var users = [ { name: 'Pablito', email: 'pablito@face.com', age: 72}, { name: 'Sofia', email: 'sofia@gmail.com', age: 39 } ]

var value = 'sofia@gmail.com'
var key = 'email'


var encontrarUsuario = users.findIndex( (parametro) => parametro.key == value)
var usuarioEncontrado = users[encontrarUsuario]
```

La salida que espero deberia ser: { name: 'Sofia', email: 'sofia@gmail.com', age: 39 }

¿Alguna idea de como hacer que lo use como parametro?

Answer (score 0):

Usar `parametro.key` es incorrecto, porque `parametro` no tiene ninguna clave que sea `key`. Usa como condición `parametro[key] == value` y te funcionará.

De cualquier manera te hago algunas recomendaciones en cuanto a tu código:

1. Lo que recibe tu callback es un `user`, no hay ninguna razón para nombrarlo como `parámetro` prestándose a confusión y no dejando claro la naturaleza del objeto que recibe la función. De hecho, esa probablemente sea la causa de tu confusión.
2. Puedes ahorrarte una línea utilizando `find` o `filter` en lugar de `findIndex`
3. Usa `let` en lugar de `var` para tus variables. Usar `var` se considera mala práctica.
4. Programa todo en español, o programa todo en inglés, el mezclar hace que el código sea ilegible y es también mala práctica.

Aplicando estas recomendaciones, tu código quedaría:

```js
let users = [ { name: 'Pablito', email: 'pablito@face.com', age: 72}, { name: 'Sofia', email: 'sofia@gmail.com', age: 39 } ]

let value = 'sofia@gmail.com'
let key = 'email'


let foundUserIndex = users.findIndex( user => user[key] == value)
var foundUser = users[foundUserIndex]

console.log(foundUser)
```

Alternativamente usando `find` o `filter`:

```js
let users = [ { name: 'Pablito', email: 'pablito@face.com', age: 72}, { name: 'Sofia', email: 'sofia@gmail.com', age: 39 } ]

let value = 'sofia@gmail.com'
let key = 'email'


var foundUserWithFilter = users.filter( user => user[key] == value)
var foundUserWithFind = users.find( user => user[key] == value)

console.log(foundUserWithFilter)
console.log(foundUserWithFind)
```